# Why does Eval statement show the wrong image

Tags: html, asp.net

SQL (`Active` column is of type `bit`):

```
id      Question            Active
1       Weather today       1
```

ASP.net `Eval`:

```
<img src='<%# Eval("Active") == "1" ? "images/active.png" : "images/inactive.png" %>' />
```

HTML:

```
<img src="images/inactive.png">
```

Why is the inactive.png image showing and not the active.

Comment: What type is Active column in DB?

Comment: `bit`. I tried checking to see if it's `True` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Most likely you need `(bool)Eval("Active") == true`

Comment: @Andrei Wow i tried that before it didn't work. Now I tried it again and it works :/... Thank you.

Comment: Np. added an answer to document that better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit fields correspond to boolean. Also you need to do a type conversion to ensure right comparison is done, as Eval outputs just object. So:

```
(bool)Eval("Active") == true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to cast the result:

```
((int)Eval("Active")) == 1 ? [...]
```

or as mentioned in the comments to a `bool`:

```
((bool)Eval("Active")) == true ? [...]
```

Comment: I thought that work but it didn't. This is what I get: `CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'`

Comment: You could try to cast it to an `int`. I'll update my answer